# How to scrape data from a website using Python 2?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-2.x

So when I run this code I keep getting empty brackets instead of the actual data.

I am trying to figure out why sense I don't receive any error messages.

```
import urllib
import re
symbolslist = ["aapl","spy","goog","nflx"]


for symbol in symbolslist:
    url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=%s&ql=1"%(symbol)
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    regex = '<span id="yfs_184_%s">(.+?)</span>'%(symbol.lower())
    pattern = re.compile(regex)
    price = re.findall(pattern, htmltext)
    print price
```

Comment: Simple print statements can be very helpful for informal debugging.

Answer (score 1):

The brackets come up because the element code for regex is not 184 its l84 its an L not a one.

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of libraries around which can help you to scrape sites. Take a look at [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org) or at [Beautiful Soup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4) they should support both Python 2 and 3 as far as I know.

Comment: I was able to figure this out  when copying the element it changes it to a 1 (one) but its actually an l (L lowercase).